# Show the Get-Credential Box when PS script is called from a PHP script

Tags: php, powershell, iis

My php script:

```
$pscommand = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command .\script.ps1 -upn $upn";
$output = shell_exec ($pscommand);
echo "<br>$output";
```

runs this ps script:

```
try{
    $credential = Get-Credential
    Import-Module MSOnline
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential -ErrorAction Stop -verbose
}
```

but the Pop-Up window to type the credential is not showing.
The Error Message is (Google Translate from german):

"Displaying a modal dialog box or form is an invalid operation if the application is not running in UserInteractive mode. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly format to view service application notifications."

How can I fix this? Is this a PS, php or IIS issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you currently calling it from php? Just starting a `powershell.exe` child process?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Basic fact is that you won't see any dialog from session 0.

Comment: I think you would need to pass the variables  to powershell in a secure way to create a [PSCredential object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0), that you can use in the powershell script. Maybe you can even create a credential object directly and pass it to the powershell part but I don't know that much about PHP...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sorry I do it like you mean

Comment: @mchief29 please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61408184/edit) with the code, comments suck for that :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have just edited my first post ;)

Comment: PowerShell script generate any pop-up window that need user interaction will not work with iis.